# Как задать 2 фона с разным раположением?

Tags: html, css, background

Приветствую! Как можно сделать два фона в одном блоке с разным расположением?
Первый фон выравнивается по правой стороне, без повторений, а второй фон-картинка в виде небольшого градиента будет снизу блока с повторениями по горизонтали.

Comment: В этот блок помести два тега `span`.Размести их как хочешь а потом задай им соответствующие фоны.

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `background` поддерживает несколько значений. К примеру:

```css
body {
  background:
    /* картинка справа без повторений */
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFzjg.jpg) right center / auto auto no-repeat fixed,
    /* небольшой градиент снизу с повторениями по горизонтали */
    linear-gradient(to right, red 10px, yellow 20px, green 30px) left bottom / 40px 10px repeat-x;

  /* чисто для демонстрации, пусть страница занимает весь экран */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```